# Windows Workflow 4.0 for Simple Orchestration?

Tags: xaml, workflow-foundation, orchestration

I have 4 classes, each with a couple of methods (all the same, they implement a common Interface) and a Dictionary<> containing stuff the instances need to know to do work. They operate serially, "A" finishes and then writes some stuff to state (either file or a DB), then "B" does its work, then "C", then "D". Right now a console app just runs each.

I will soon come on a time when I need to put something between "A" and "B", and later "C" and "D". You get the idea.

I thought that Windows Workflow on Framework 4.0 would be a good candidate for simple sequence orchestration. So I added a new XAML file, fired up the designer, and.... I'm not sure what to do next. I just want to instance objects and set their Dictionary and run them.

How can I get started with that? Simple orchestration searches on Google are not helping.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to help the next WF newbie:

Open the designer.

Drag a "Sequence" onto the design surface.

Drag an "InvokeMethod" inside the Sequence.

Target type should be null for Instance Types.

Target object should be "New my.namespace.my.class" (note New is VBasic syntax, required even if you are doing C#)

MethodName should have the name of the method you want to call.

Get Properties and click the elipsis and add the properties in the same order as they are specified in the class definition in your code.

Done.

I stumbled for a while until I found the right word to Bing for - InvokeMethod is the sweetness that lets you run custom code as an activity. There are at least 99e99 other ways to do it I am sure, but this is what works for me.

Thanks.